# Duplex printing with Samsung ML-2165W requires manual feed

Tags: samsung, duplex-printing

I have a Samsung ML-2165W printer and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. The printer works fine except for the duplex printing.

Duplex printing requires to manually feed the paper after each printing, so if I try to print an eight-page document, in two-sided mode, after printed the first page I have to take the paper, put it in the tray and press the button - after each printed page!

In Windows 7 it works properly, first it prints all the pages on a same side, so you can take all the papers together, put it back in the tray, press the button and it will print the other side. At the end you have your document ready to read.

How can I have this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!
Gnome-manual-duplex do exactly what I want.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/g-manual-duplex/

Works fine with my printer, even if it's not on the supported printers list.